# how to store objects of class file in an array in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsarray

i am new in iphone app development.So please help me out. I am trying to develop an application in which i need to display contacts name number and image in a table view.I have a class file named Records.h and Records.m having three objects of NSString type name, number and image. i select data from the database and store each data in the objects of this class file like this :

```
Records *data = [[Records alloc] init];

data.contactname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];

            data.contactnumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];

            data.contactimage = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];
```

And then i store this class file in `NSMutableArray`:

```
[array addObject:data];
```

such that at the every index i have each object with all the three strings name,number and image. Now i want to select only the name part from the every index. Any idea how to do it..??

Comment: Simple, check the code added below: 
In your tableview datasource method: cellForRowAtIndexPath : 
Record *record = [array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
now you can fetch, record.contactname, record.ctnumber, record.ctimage, etc.

Comment: Working..!! Thanks Mrunal.. :)

Comment: I have implemented this. But i am facing a problem. Everytime the label is getting the same text. Like i have two name paul and john.But in the table view both cells are displaying the same name Paul. The select query is returning the correct data from the database. Here is the code: data = [namelist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; UILabel *lbl; lbl = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1]; lbl.text = data.contactname ;

Comment: Can you please add your new code, which you have added in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Thanks Mrunal. The problem has now been solved. Actually i have allocated memory for the object of my class only once there by not allowing to create memory for the new object.
 
Records *data = [[Records alloc] init];
i have declared this a t the wrong place actually.

Comment: OK.. Great that it got resolved.. If you think it has been helpful to you then can you please up vote my comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath method write following code :

```
Records *shareObj = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
label.text=shareobj.name;
label2.text=shareobj.contactnumber;
```

Comment: I have implemented this. But i am facing a problem. Everytime the label is getting the same text. Like i have two name paul and john.But in the table view both cells are displaying the same name Paul. The select query is returning the correct data from the database.
Here is the code:
data = [namelist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    UILabel *lbl;
    lbl = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    lbl.text = data.contactname ;

Comment: The problem has now been solved. Actually i have allocated memory for the object of my class only once there by not allowing to create memory for the new object. Records *data = [[Records alloc] init]; i have declared this a t the wrong place actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   Records *objRecord = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"Name :: %@", objRecord.name);

   lbl.title.text = objRecord.name;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //in . h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *labelContactName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *labelContactNumber;

//in . m file
 _labelContactName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 230, 32)];

    _lableContactName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:_labelContactName];

      _labelContactNumber= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 27, 110, 20)];

    _lableContactNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    [cell.contentView addSubview:_labelContactNumber];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Records *objRecord = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"Name :: %@", objRecord.name);
_lableContactName.text=objRecord.name;
}
```